# Kashima coat or not?

Tags: mountain-bike, parts, upgrades

I have some Fox Float 32 Evolution 140mm travel forks on my 2015 giant trance. I ride very aggressively and it's a bumpy ride down a lot of the tracks I do. Keep in mind I do technical tracks, over roots, drops etc.
Today I rode a bike with 150mm pikes and I didn't feel a thing at all. 
I'm wondering if getting kashima coat on my forks would:
1. Make them less bumpy (smoother)?
2. How much would it cost?
3. Would it just be more worth saving up for some pikes?

Feel free to ask questions! Cheers

Comment: I would guess you'd have to buy a new fork.

Comment: I am confused.  "Today I rode a bike with 150mm pikes with the same fork as mine and I didn't feel a thing at all."  So was it not the same fork as yours?

Comment: @ChrisinAK just noticed that now, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would

1. Make sure your sag is set correctly. See fork manual.
2. Place a zip-tie on your fork leg to act as a max-travel gauge, it lets you see how far from bottoming out you were on any ride and will aid you with tuning.
3. Play with the compression/rebound settings on your current fork. If ride is too harsh, reduce both.
4. If you are unable to smooth out the ride, or it is at the expense of a wallowy ride, have them serviced (new oil, seals as needed etc).
5. Avoid large-bill outlays on the current fork while saving up for a better fork in case you can't improve the ride enough. You fork (and bike) will have some resale value, but putting money into it won't increase the resale value.

Comment: I will do the sag again and try that and look into a service. Cheers!

Comment: You may want to also compare apples to apples when possible.  I think there are things with suspension setup (pressures, rebound, total travel, frame geometry, etc) that will make far more difference than the coating.

Comment: I've done a new sag test and set that all up again. Is smoother already. Next time I go for a ride I'll fine tune it and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

You have previously been able to purchase replacement Fox Kashima CSUs (crown/ steerer/ upper) that many companies will install as an aftermarket option on OEM forks.

1. Not that you would notice, as user2480585 has stated bumpiness of a ride is generally a tune issue rather than a fork issue. The 32 Evolution is a more than capable fork and if you were an advanced rider you're unlikely to feel the difference that the kashima coating would make.
2. A few years ago it was about $200 in the US but can't find much to verify that today.
3. I' don't think Pikes would be your best option unless you were looking to spend a bit more on the bike. The Pikes are more at home on a more aggressive trail bike (Trance SX). You can get a 140mm Pike on the SX but I think you will find something else limiting the rest of you're bike as your riding gets more aggressive. You find all kind of things to replace such as brakes, drive train, shock, wheels and cockpit chasing a more aggressive bike. I would look to upgrade the whole bike rather than the fork.

Comment: I've rode a 2013 stunt jumper that was when new very similar to my bike. The guys put pikes on, upgraded the brakes tires etc and it's incredibly nice to ride (and he rides more aggressively than me). That's what I'm hoping to do to my bike, over time that is. But thanks for the input, I'll look at other bikes and see if it would just be worthwhile getting a new one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote, first tune your fork, and keep it clean. I use some silicon spray as well on the stanchion tubes and dust seals.
If you have coil spring in your fork (not air only), be sure it's for your weight - if not, swap it.
If still not satisfied, you can check how low or high-end is the damper cartridge in your fork. Cheaper forks can feel OK but not in a wide range of conditions. High-end dampers are more versatile, perform better on high speeds too.
My opinion is that "open oil bath" system forks are the smoothest, though not the lightest.